# Proving that this sigmoid sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds, monotone-functions

##### The problem

Given $h_0=0.6$ I want to prove that the following iterative sequence converges. I also want to find **the value it converges to**.

$$h_{t+1}= \sigma(3h_t-1)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(3h_t-1)}}$$

##### My attempt

We can show that $h_{t+1}$ is increasing with respect to the previous value:

$$\frac{dh_{t+1}}{dh_t}=\frac{3e^{-(3h_t-1)}}{(1+e^{-(3h_t-1)})^2} > 0$$

Although I've shown this, I cannot prove that $h_{t+1}$ > $h_t$. I can only show that $h_1$>$h_0$ by actually finding $h_1$.

$$h_1 = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(1.8-1)}}=0.69 > h_0$$

Then, it can iteratively be proven that each next h is greater than the previous, since:
$$h_1 > h_0 => \sigma(3h_1-1) > σ(3h_0-1)=>h_2 > h_1 \\ h_2>h_1=>\sigma(3h_2 - 1)>\sigma(3h_1-1)=>h_3>h_2$$

But I'm not sure if that's correct and there has to be a cleaner way to show this.

And I'm still far from proving convergence. I thought I had a clue about the converging value, since this is a sigmoid and has an upper bound of $1$. But upon thinking of it, the convergence value cannot be $1$ since the next $h$ would be smaller.

##### Another idea

We could just impose that $h_{t+1}=h_t$, but this did not lead me anywhere either. Or to be more precise, I could not solve for $h_t$.

$$h_{t}=\sigma(3h_t-1)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(3h_t+1)}}$$

Comment: I just note that the initial value is crucial here for the sequence to be increasing. It converges in both cases, so if you start above the limit (as computed in the accepted answer), it would be a decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show: $\{h_n\}$ increasing sequence by induction on $n \ge 0$. This means we show: $h_{n+1} > h_n, n \ge 0$. The base case $n = 0$, we have: $h_1 = 0.69 > 0.6 = h_0$. Assume $h_n > h_{n-1}, n \ge 1$, we show: $h_{n+1} > h_n$. We have: $h_n > h_{n-1} \implies 3h_n - 1 > 3h_{n-1} - 1\implies e^{3h_n-1} > e^{3h_{n-1}-1}\implies e^{-(3h_n-1)} < e^{-(3h_{n-1}-1)}\implies 1+e^{-(3h_n-1)} < 1+e^{-(3h_{n-1}-1)}\implies \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-(3h_n-1)}}> \dfrac{1}{1+3^{-(3h_{n-1}-1)}}\implies h_{n+1} > h_n. $. Thus the sequence $\{h_n\}$ is strictly increasing. Since it is bounded above by $1$, it converges to a value $L$ which satisfies the equation: $L = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-(3L-1)}}$.We can verify $L$ with wolfgram alpha and get $L \approx 0.8041$.